# Why my Html function in R is not working:?

Tags: r, htmltools

This is my code:

```
card_function <- function(title,paragraph,tags){
  div(
    class = "card",
    div(class = "header"),
    div(
      class = "info",
      p(class = "title", 'title'),
      p('paragraph')
    ),
    div(
      class = "footer",
      p(class = "tag", 'tags'),
      tags$button(id = "action", "Get started")
    ))
}

card_function(title = 'Titulo',paragraph = 'paragrafo',tags = 'HTML')
```

This is my error message:

```
Error in tags$button : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I already tried to remove tags from `tags$button` but it didnt work.

Any help?

Comment: This is because you have defined `tags = "HTML"` as an argument in your function. R does not seem to work out that `tags$button(id = "action", "Get started")` refers to `shiny::tags$button()`. Call the argument `tag_names` or something and it should be fine.

Comment: ... or use `shiny::tags$button` inside your function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either u can use tags$button syntax directly or simply use the div function to create a button-like element. I replaced button(id = "action", "Get started") with div(id = "action", "Get started", class = "button"). This should work regardless of whether you are using Shiny or not.

```
card_function <- function(title, paragraph, tags) {
  div(
    class = "card",
    div(class = "header"),
    div(
      class = "info",
      p(class = "title", title),
      p(paragraph)
    ),
    div(
      class = "footer",
      p(class = "tag", tags),
      div(id = "action", "Get started", class = "button")
    )
  )
}

# Example usage
card_function(title = 'Titulo', paragraph = 'paragrafo', tags = 'HTML')
```

using library as directed by @SamR, you can avoid the conflict with the tags object from the shiny package, either by changing the argument name from tags to tag_names,  or by using shiny::tags$button as directed by @r2evans, Here I changed tags to tag_names.

```
library(shiny)
card_function <- function(title, paragraph, tag_names) {
  div(
    class = "card",
    div(class = "header"),
    div(
      class = "info",
      p(class = "title", title),
      p(paragraph)
    ),
    div(
      class = "footer",
      p(class = "tag", tag_names),
      tags$button(id = "action", "Get started", class = "button")
    )
  )
}

# Example usage
card_function(title = 'Titulo', paragraph = 'paragrafo', tag_names = 'HTML')
```